# How to reuse Images in Java and avoid using streams so much?

Tags: java, performance, stream, vaadin

I have 5 pictures as files that I want to reuse for multiple rows of my Vaadin-Grid. I noticed that I have to load the pictures again and again per a stream to make it work. The following way didnt work for me and I cant explain it to me.

(`Image` is `com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Image;` from Vaadin 14)

I load the image like the following. I removed the error handling to make it easier to read.

```
public static Image loadImage(...) {
        File file = new File(filepath);
        var bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, getFileExtension(filepath), bout);

        var bytes = bout.toByteArray();
        StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(defaultNameImage, () -> new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));

        bout.close();
        return new Image(resource, defaultNameImage);
}
```

Each row of the grid is created like the following (simplified):

```
private Entry createEntry(...) {
    var image = UtilFile.loadImage(PATH_TO_IMAGE, DEFAULT_NAME);
    return new Entry(image);
}
```

The real issue appears if I want to access the image again to show it in the UI.

```
    grid.addColumn(new ComponentRenderer<Image, Entry>(entry -> { 
        return entry.getImage(); // Here is the trouble
        }
    })).setHeader("Image");
```

Only one Image is shown instead 1 for every row. Is this because the stream can only be used once? I would have guessed that the new instance of Image would have the image. I am a bit confused, sorry.

Now the concrete questions:

1. Why does my way not work? Is the stream used only once and the other instances of Image don't get the loaded image?
2. Is it possible to avoid using the streams so much? I would like to simply keep the Image in memory and reuse it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless you’re performing format conversions, loading the image, just to store it again, is entirely obsolete, `new StreamResource(defaultNameImage, () -> new FileInputStream(filepath))` would be sufficient.

Comment: Is making a new stream for each file faster than loading it once and keep it in the memory?

Comment: First of all, keeping it in memory only pays off if the stream truly is read a lot of times, but I would be very surprised if that framework really requires *you* to implement the caching (again for every resource). Further, even if you want to do caching, you should simply read the bytes from the file and provide them, instead of decoding the Image and encoding it again. E.g. `byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filepath)); return new Image(new StreamResource(defaultNameImage, () -> new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)), defaultNameImage);`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. This make the situatoin more clear for me!

Comment: But as said, I doubt that you are responsible for implementing caching when using such a framework. So just use `new FileResource(new File(filepath))`…